# Which way is better for calling multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wondering which way of calling mutiple components is better. Here we have example one which calls components in a composition type way another word for this would be (High-order functions???)

```js
var App = React.createClass({
    render:function () {
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
});

// Title Component
var Title = React.createClass({
    render:function () {
        return(
            <App>
                <div className="text-center">
                    <h1>Rock App</h1>
                    <h4>An Easy Way To Track Your Rock Climbing Progress</h4>
                </div>
                {this.props.children}
            </App>
        )
    }
});

// Login Component
var Login = React.createClass({
    render:function () {
        return(
            <Title>
                <div>
                    <form className="form-horizontal">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div className="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div className="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </Title>

        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Login/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here you would call Login, which is within Title which is within App.

Another way is to create each component separately and have a main parent component which calls each sub-component children attributes like so...

```js
var Title = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
       return(
           <div className="head text-center">
               <h1>Rock App</h1>
               <h3>The only app you need to track your climbs</h3>
           </div>
       )
   }
});

var Login = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return(
            <div>
                <form className="form-horizontal">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" className="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="password" className="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Homepage = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <Title>{this.props.children}</Title>
                    <Login>{this.props.children}</Login>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});




ReactDOM.render(<Homepage/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

In my opinion the second way is much cleaner and is not dependent on other components. But I am just figuring out what way is standard.

Answer (score 0):

this is straight from the React documentation:

> When designing interfaces, break down the common design elements
>   (buttons, form fields, layout components, etc.) into reusable
>   components with well-defined interfaces. That way, the next time you
>   need to build some UI, you can write much less code. This means faster
>   development time, fewer bugs, and fewer bytes down the wire.

The beauty of React is being able to structure your application into simple, reusable components and have the option to pass data from the parent to the child components. So by having all your components in one file it's basically defeating the main objective of React.

I personally like to have an index file that handles my middleware and routes, and then a parent file for each section that handles imports and passing data down.